# fncychap, book with different table of contents' heading

Tags: table-of-contents, fncychap

I have a problem with my book. I'm studying LaTex since 3 months, so I'm not an expert.
Anyway, I'm using the fncychap package but I'd like to have a different table of contents' heading. In detail, I don't know how to overcome the fncychap settings and, in particular how to reduce the distance between the table of contents and the upper headings.
This is the code part that is interested in the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{book}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{quoting}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[head=30pt,foot=10pt, height=165mm, top=2.3cm, bottom=1.8cm ]{geometry}

\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{verse}

%imposta il titolo dei capitoli con poco spazio dal bordo superiore
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
%aggiusta la distanza dal bordo superiore peri titoli di 'fncychap'
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-20\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-20\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTI}{\vskip 80\p@}{\vskip 40\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTIS}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 0\p@}{}{}
\makeatother

%gestione del formato dell'indice
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{%
    \fontencoding{T1}
    %\fontfamily{garamond}
    \fontseries{m}
    \fontshape{it}
    \fontsize{11}{13}
    \selectfont
}
\begin{document}
%---crea indice 
    \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \frontmatter
\chapter {Introduzione}
\chapter [Poesie d'amore o ai suoi confini]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\raggedleft Poesie d'amore\\
             o ai suoi confini}}
\end{document}
```

Problably the solution is very easy, but I really can't find it.
And, regarding the code, probably something is superfluous, so if someone could also help me in understanding how to razionalize.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more detail regarding your request: "to overcome the fncychap settings and, in particular how to reduce the distance between the table of contents and the upper headings"? Are you referring to the distance from the bottom of the rectangular block to the first entry in the ToC?

Comment: Sorry for my abstruse question. I try to clarify.

Comment: I need to reduce the space between the upper header and tow how the top part of the TOC. But, first I'd like to know how to creat a different header for the TOC, taking in count that fncychap sets all headers, and using the code aboce I can't do this.

Comment: Well, my typewriting is awful...

Comment: I need to reduce the space between the upper header and the top part of the TOC. But, first I'd like to know how to create a different header for the TOC, taking in count that fncychap sets all headers, and using the code above I can't do this. Hope someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Let's deal with one thing at a time, and only ask one question in this Q&A at a time. The first question should be that you want to create a unique `fncychap` for some chapter within your document. In this case it would be the ToC. Update your question to this and includes details of what you want it to look like which is different from the rest. Then, if there are more questions, ask them as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

To change the heading of the table of contents, add the line

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My new TOC title}}
```

somewhere before `\begin{document}`, or add the command

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My new TOC title}
```

between `\begin{document}` and `\tableofcontents`.

To reduce the gap between the table of contents and its heading, add the command

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-5ex}}
```

shortly after `\begin{document}` (modify the number as needed). You can also add the command to the `\AddBeginDocument` command above, resulting in

```
\AtBeginDocument
  {\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My new TOC title}%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-5ex}}%
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. Exacly what I was looking for.